# android.se.omapi.SEService: My app doesn't connect with the OnConnectedListener

Tags: android, applet, globalplatform

I am trying to create an application that transmits APDUs to a SIMCARD using the OMAPI libraries, but the OnConnected listener for SEService is never called.

I followed the structure I found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/secure_element/omapi/src/android/omapi/cts/OmapiTest.java

I wait up to 30 seconds to see if the `OnConnectedListener` method is called, but that never happens. I always get the error that I left in the code: `throw new TimeoutException( "Service could not be connected after " + SERVICE_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT + "ms");`

The SIMCARD I use contains the ARA-M applet, and the necessary SHA-1 keys, that is, the application obtains carrier privileges.
In another application using the TelephonyManager libraries I have had success transmitting APDUs.

Please can you help me understand if I am doing something wrong?
Do I need to declare some permission in the manifest of my application?

Thank you in advance.

I leave you part of the code that I implemented:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity [...]{
     /*FOR OMAPI*/
    private final Object serviceMutex = new Object();
    private SEService seService;
    private boolean connected = false;
    private Timer connectionTimer;
    private ServiceConnectionTimerTask mTimerTask = new ServiceConnectionTimerTask();
    private final long SERVICE_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT = 30000;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      [...]
                setUp(getApplicationContext());

                try {
                    waitForConnection();
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                Reader[] readers = seService.getReaders();
                byte [] apdu = {(byte)0x80, (byte)0x02, (byte)0xfC, (byte)0x00};

                for (Reader reader : readers){

                    byte [] response = new byte[0];
                    try {
                        response = Util.internalTransmitAPDU(reader, apdu);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    Log.i("response OMAPI", String.valueOf(response));
                }

   }


    public void setUp(Context context){

        seService = new SEService(context, new SynchronousExecutor(), mListener);
        connectionTimer = new Timer();
        connectionTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, SERVICE_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
    }

    static class SynchronousExecutor implements Executor {
        public void execute(Runnable r) {
            r.run();
        }
    }

    private final SEService.OnConnectedListener mListener = () -> {
        synchronized (serviceMutex){
            connected = true;
            serviceMutex.notify();
            Log.i("OMAPI", "EntraOnconnect");
        }


    private void waitForConnection() throws TimeoutException {
        synchronized (serviceMutex) {
            if (!connected) {
                try {
                    serviceMutex.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (!connected && !seService.isConnected()) {
                throw new TimeoutException(
                        "Service could not be connected after " + SERVICE_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT
                                + " ms");
            }
            if (connectionTimer != null) {
                connectionTimer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Your app is using the prober signature matching the Sha hash? Also waiting 30 seconds might not be enough, at least during the startup of Android. When it is running it should be much faster. Also, instead of the timeout use object wait/notify and wake up in the listener.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will apply the suggestions.

Regarding the HASH: Yes, the SIMCARD correctly registers the HASH which matches the SHA-1 with which the app is signed. Luckily I can capture the traffic between the SIM and the cell phone and confirm that the HASH is correctly recorded on the SIM.
With Telephonymanager.hasCarrierPrivileges() I verify that the app has carrier privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` permission. Maybe this is missing.

Could you also try to use a different `Executor` instead `SynchronousExecutor`? E.g.:

```java
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
```

Maybe your code is blocked if not running in a different thread.

Comment: The following permissions are declared in the manifest:

    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> `
     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> `
     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" /> `
     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> `
     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`
sorry for not adding this info in the initial discussion